# C# Very strange behaviour writing text in file

Tags: c#, file

I am using following code in C# to log some text in a file...

```
class Logger{

    public void log(String text)
    {
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"\\log.txt", true);
        file.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss: " + text.ToString()));
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

I call the logger like this:

```
Logger logger = new Logger();
logger.log("some text.");
```

Once I run the program, in the console seems everything right, but in the file it appears like:

```
- 2019-08-02 09:31:32: C:U32er32Danisourcerepo32Free+2e an2 RollouFree+2e an2 RolloubinDebud.C.Repo32ior19 1 Dev20190802_093132_56029iner7ace creae2!
- 2019-08-02 09:31:32: 7ree+2e au7 Dev bed.C.inn!
```

Any idea what I have to change in the code? I expect that the text is readable :-)

Thanks for the help!

Regards, Daniel

Comment: Not directly related, but why not use existing loggers like NLog or Log4net or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss: " + text.ToString())
```

Needs to be:

```
 DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + ": " + text
```

You don't want to run your `text` through the date formatting.